# How can I control the float number precision in table of reportlab?

Tags: python, numbers, precision, reportlab

I'm creating a table using reportlab with Python 3.7.
I wonder if there is a way to change the float number decimal precision.

for example, now the float number in one cell is 4.33333333.
I want to change it to 4.33 using table style option.

Changing float number to string with 2 digit places is not an option as I need to calculate with those numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with reportlab but in python you can use string formatting like this:

```py
print('{0:.2f}'.format(4.33333333))
>> 4.33

print('{0:.4f}'.format(4.33333333))
>> 4.3333
```